# How to append/update multidepth object in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, object, append, updating

I am having trouble understanding how to append or update data in objects

so lets say I have a an Object with data which looks like this following schema of the object I want to add to in schema after running this command

```
$testdata | Format-Custom -Property * -Depth 6
```

```
class PSCustomObject
{
  sessions = 
    [
      class PSCustomObject
      {
        type = current
        generated = 2017-08-31T09:02:55.251Z
        windows = 
          [
            class PSCustomObject
            {
              id = 770
              incognito = False
              tabs = 
                [
                  class PSCustomObject
                  {
                    active = True
                    id = 771
                    incognito = False
                    title = Subscriptions - YouTube
                    url = https://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions
                    windowId = 770
                  }
                  class PSCustomObject
                  {
                    active = False
                    id = 776
                    incognito = False
                    title = Overly Sarcastic Productions - YouTube
                    url = https://www.youtube.com/user/RedEyesTakeWarning/videos
                    windowId = 770
                  }

                ]

            }
            class PSCustomObject
            {
              id = 773
              incognito = False
              tabs = 
                [
                  class PSCustomObject
                  {
                    active = False
                    id = 774
                    incognito = False
                    title = Technology - Google News
                    url = https://news.google.com/news/headlines/section/topic/TECHNOLOGY?ned=us&hl=en
                    windowId = 773
                  }
                  class PSCustomObject
                  {
                    active = False
                    id = 806
                    incognito = False
                    title = Microsoft PowerShell Is a Hot Hacker Target, But Its Defenses Are Improving | WIRED
                    url = https://www.wired.com/story/microsoft-powershell-security/
                    windowId = 773
                  }
                  ...
                ]
            }
          ]
      }
    ]
}
```

So Lets say I want to add a NEW TAB to the **windows** with id **770**
And the NEW Tab's **title** would be **yahoo** and the **url** would be **https://yahoo.com** and **id**  would be **9001**

How would I just add just that new entry into the tabs without having to recreate the whole object?

Comment: Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve, instead of what you perceive as the solution.

Comment: Well normally when you append say...like an array or hash, you use `+=` or `$hash.add(something, $something)` , I am not understanding how you would add an object of data in a particular object...because  I cant just go `($testdata.sessions.windows.Where({$_.id -eq 770}).tabs) += $newtabobject` because that doesnt seem to work when i try it, despite it being the same in setup as the other tab objects

Comment: How are you creating the `$testdata` object?

Comment: its just an import of a json file ... `$testdata = Get-content $file | Convertfrom-json` ... is what im running here.... I dont create the scheme, nor want to... it needs to be left as is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this isn't really an answer, but more like a work around.

I myself do not understand how to modify objects in Powershell like you want there. Normally a simple `+=` generally works for most things.

But, for your problem, which seems to be attempting to add an object with key value pairs within a SPECIFIC object with a SPECIFIC id straight up `+=` is not going to work, because you are trying to parse your way into it. You are only going to get a stupid error of the **Property not being found** or something.

The way I do it, if it is a static list and the order/position WONT change before I update it, is to get the **INDEX** of the particular object I wish to add to.  And then do a simple `+=` of your data object/hash to what ever object you wish to modify based on the index.

*Like the Following:*

First, prepare your New Object or Hash with your Key Value pairs.

```
 $newhash = @{}
 $newhash.Add("title","yahoo") 
 $newhash.Add("url", "https://yahoo.com")
 $newhash.Add("id", "9001")
```

Next, Find the index of the Object you wish to modify/add-to with `.IndexOf()`, like your id 770

```
$position = $testdata.sessions.windows.id.IndexOf(770)
```

This should tell you what position in the list of objects your object with the particular id of **770** is

Now, quite literally, do the simple `+=` to the tabs of the specific window you wanted to add/modify to.

```
$testdata.sessions.windows[$position].tabs += $newhash
```

if you are confused, using `[]` after something indicates choosing its position on a list, like **[0]** being the first and so on so forth.

That SHOULD be it.

NOTE: This DOES NOT work for scenarios where the data is updated before you update it and the positions change before you get to modify it.

I realize this might NOT be what you are looking for, but still.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are correct that it is not specifically what I am looking for, but it DOES help. So in a sense, my problem is solved, granted not the way i'd like it.